# Vertx: Log4j2 without using the vertx logger factory

Tags: log4j2, vert.x

I would like to use Log4j2 without losing its API like passing lambdas for lazy loading.

So, I would like to avoid to use Vertx LoggerFactory (returning generic Logger API) and use the Log4j2 directly.

Is there any serious drawback to consider when Log4j2 is used directly without using the Vertx logger factory?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no serious drawback and it's rather the opposite: use log4j2 without going through Vert.x logging!

Vert.x logging is deprecated and will be completely internal in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use log4j2 directly without using org.slf4j.Logger, however it seems that custom appenders are created twice, once by log4j2 and then once by vertx.